# How can I merge 2 images on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, bitmapimage, writeablebitmap

I have 2 images and I want to merge them into one on my apps in Windows Phone.

The first image captured by my WP's camera, the second image is a frame (borders, filter, etc.) which user can choose among our templates. So how can I merge them into one.

Thanks and best regards.

Comment: It's not clear what you're looking to do.

Comment: @ Michael Petrotta : I edited it.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "merge", exactly, on a pixel level?

Comment: I mean the border frame overlaps the captured picture, just like 2 layers on photoshop.

Comment: So you want to add the pixel values? What do you want to do if both images encode non-black values for the same pixel, or will that never happen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't quite understand what you ask. But I guess you want to overlay 1 image on top of another. If so, there is already an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9677987/476917). Inside the `<grid>`, you can provide both the image, and customize the opacity of each image to make it overlay-ed.

**EDITED:**
You can use Writeablebitmap for that and there's an already library for that [here](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/). After adding the WriteableBitmapExWinPhone in your WP7 project, you can merge the image and frame by doing this:

```
    var photo = ...//you writeablebitmap of image here
    var frame = ...//your writeablebitmap of frame here
    var merge = new WriteableBitmap(435, 435); //size of merge canvas
    merge .Clear(Colors.White); //white background
    merge.Blit(new Rect(oX, oY, w, h), photo, new Rect(0, 0, photo.PixelWidth,        photo.PixelHeight)); //draw the photo first
    merge.Blit(new Rect(0, 0, 435, 435), frame, new Rect(0, 0, frame.PixelWidth,        frame.PixelHeight)); //draw the frame
```

Comment: Thank Agung Pratama: just what I want to do.