# how to write text on a image using windows phone code?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1.1

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Write text on image in WP7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674649/write-text-on-image-in-wp7)

I have an app and one of the feature I want to add to it is , sending the picture with some text on top of it.IS that possible to code this in windows phone ?

Comment: Yes it is possible. What have you tried that isn't working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easy way is just rendering a TextBlock with the text on a WriteableBitmap

```csharp
private void RenderString(WriteableBitmap bitmap, string stringToRender)
{
    TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();
    textBlock.Text = stringToRender;

    // set font, size, etc. on textBlock

    bitmap.Render(textBlock, null);
    bitmap.Invalidate();
}
```

Comment: Can we place this textblock anywhere on the picture ?

Comment: Yes, just set the `Margin` property of the TextBox before rendering it!