# Can I place two badge values on a WP8 live tile?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I want to place two int badge values on my app's live tile; I've seen examples for updating one value, but I need two, one above/below the other. is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps write a textblock on the picture and then set it as livetile?

[how to write text on a image using windows phone code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13979607/how-to-write-text-on-a-image-using-windows-phone-code)