# merge text and image in single writable bitmap image through c# in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I need to merge text with an image in single writable bitmap image through c# in windows phone 8 app. But I don't know how to merge text with image so that i can get a single writable bitmap image. Can any one help me? I tried this code for image but don't know how to add text with image?

```
Uri uri = new Uri("Images/Unlocked.png", UriKind.Relative);
StreamResourceInfo resourceInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(uri);
BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
img.SetSource(resourceInfo.Stream);
WriteableBitmap writeableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(img);
```

Comment: I converted a single image in writable bitmap image but don't know how to add text in it.

Comment: Are there non-writable bitmaps? I'm sorry, but you've provided no code. Please use search engine - writing text to a bitmap has been raised many times on SO in all C# frameworks.

Comment: @AnandDubey You can edit the question by clicking edit button which is in end of the your post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are already couple of good examples: [MSDN](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Render-text-on-bitmap-fff2b406), [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13979607/how-to-write-text-on-a-image-using-windows-phone-code).

Following them your code could look like this:

```
BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
bitmap.SetSource(App.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Images/Unlocked.png", UriKind.Relative)).Stream);
TextBlock drawString = new TextBlock();
drawString.Text = "Simple text";
drawString.FontSize = 12;

WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(bitmap);
wb.Render(drawString, null);
wb.Invalidate();
```

You have already set the image of your `WritableBimap`, then you have to [Render](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.render(v=vs.95).aspx) something on it - any `UIELement` - not only TextBlock.