# How to write a text on image in c# for windows phone 8?

Tags: image, text, merge, windows-phone-8, text-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Write text on image in WP7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674649/write-text-on-image-in-wp7)

I want take a picture from camera or media library in windows phone 8 programmatically and write a some text on this photo and the text have resizable,rotate,etc..,after that merge this photo and text in single layer, please help me Thanks in Advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674649/write-text-on-image-in-wp7 check this

Answer (score 1):

Just put TextBlock control on Image control.

```
  <Grid>
   <Image source="source"/>
   <TextBlock Text="text"/>
  </Grid>
```

To TextBlock You can set margin and it will be on Image Control.
You can resize, change font, change rotation and make animation on TextBlock.

Comment: It's good, But i want take a photo from gallery or camera and write some text into the photo......